# Analysing multiple columns with ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova

I am using the following code to analyse my data

```
aov.models <- lapply(setdiff(names(mtcars), "cyl"), function(s) {
  aov(as.formula(paste(s, " ~ cyl")),mtcars)
})
```

-However, I am not sure how to print the list of list output to a textfile (I have tried flatten but get the error: `Error in as.character.factor(x) : malformed factor)`

-Can only summarise them one at a time, with e.g.
`summary(aov.models[[5]])`.

-Also, the list loses the variable names and now each entry is only a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
names <- list()
aov.models <- lapply(setdiff(names(mtcars), "cyl"), function(s) {
  names <<- append(names, s) # Note the global assignment
  aov(as.formula(paste(s, " ~ cyl")),mtcars)
})
names(aov.models) <- names

out <- capture.output(aov.models)
cat(out, file="myOutput.txt", sep="\n")
```

In response to the OP's request in the comments below.

`summary` provides the p-values, `print` (the default method implicitly called in your demo code) does not.

```
out <- capture.output(lapply(aov.models, summary))
cat(out, file="myOutput.txt", sep="\n")
```

Comment: Yes, this is really close! I'm not sure if there is some way to get the P value in the output at the moment it is just the Sum of Squares and degrees of freedom printing

Comment: well, that's because `print(aov.models)` doesn't print the p-value, and you didn't ask to see it in your problem statement!  I've modified my answer to include the p-value.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's perfect!